# Debugging Python script tool that contains space in location using PythonWin from ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, pythonwin

I have created a python script that is on a network drive, and in a folder that has spaces in the location e.g.

```
\\server\Team name\scripts\myScript.py
```

I have added the script to a script tool in ArcCatalog,and set up the parameters correctly.
When I try and debug the script (by right-clicking on the script and selecting debug), PythonWin opens as expected, but the script I specified does not open, but a blank file which has the location

```
\\server\Team
```

How do I open a script it in a script tool that has spaces in the path?

Comment: This is just one of the reasons why putting spaces in directory names is a violation of best practice.

Comment: I totally agree, but there is no way round it here unfortunately

Comment: Python does *not* like spaces. Does the folder have an 8.3 name?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: After PythonWin opens can you then navigate to, and open, myScript.py?

Comment: yep, browsing to the particular .py within PythonWin.